# Matlab replace value with zero from matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, replace

I matrix

```
A = [123   123   123    99    99    99    32    32    32    40
      40    40    22    22    34    34    34   152   152   152
      92    92    92    91    91    91   146   146   146   119
       3     3    96    96    96   136   136   136    68    68
     ]
B = [40 68 119]
```

How can I replace with zero value from A that have same value with B. required result:

```
C = [123   123   123    99    99    99    32    32    32     0
       0     0    22    22    34    34    34   152   152   152
      92    92    92    91    91    91   146   146   146     0
       3     3    96    96    96   136   136   136     0     0
     ]
```

thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ismember`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to obtain a logical mask of values of `A` that are in `B`, and then use that as a logical index to make those entries zero:

```
C = A; % define C equal to A
C(ismember(A,B)) = 0; % make elements from B equal to 0
```

Or, in a single line: multiply `A` by a mask that equals `1` for elements not in `B` and `0` for elements in `B`:

```
C = A.*~ismember(A,B); % multiply A by a mask to make elements from B equal to 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start down this road:

```
C = A;
for i = 1:numel(B)
    C(C == B(i)) = 0;
end
```

The third line uses logical indexing - `C == 20` is a logical matrix, true where the element is 20, false otherwise, and `C(C == 20) = 0` sets the true elements to `0`.